# Convert multiple string elements list to a list with single element split by comma using Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list with string elements: `lst = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, and I want to convert it to a single element list but split by `,`.

The expected list will like this:

```
['h, e, l, l, o']
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a string join:

```py
lst = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
output = [', '.join(lst)]
print(output)  # ['h, e, l, l, o']
```